# Drag columns to group datagridview

Tags: c#

Good day to all.

I am looking for a tutorial on how to create a drag and drop grouping of datagridviews as shown in the images below.

[image]

[image]

Can you help me with a link for a video or pdf tutorial on how to do it.

Thank you very much in advanced for the usual help.